# pgfplots: How to adjust the width of the drawing area?

Tags: pgfplots, width

I want to produce plots that fit into the columns of a text document. My problem is that setting `width=\linewidth` seems to apply on the axis and labels only. When I put the legend outside it sticks out of the column:
[image]

I would like to get this:

[image]

In this case I have adjusted the width manually to fit the drawing area into the column (see code below).

> Is there a way to achieve this automatically?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
%%% The following figure fits well %%%
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background]
  \begin{axis}[
    width = \linewidth,
    xlabel=x axis label,
    ylabel=y axis label,
    legend pos = {north west},
  ]
  \addplot[blue] {exp(x)};\addlegendentry{legend entry}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This figure is part of a two column document and fits perfectly}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
%%% The next figure is to large %%%
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background]
  \begin{axis}[
    width = \linewidth,
    xlabel=x axis label,
    ylabel=y axis label,
    legend pos = {outer north east},
  ]
  \addplot[red] {exp(x)};\addlegendentry{legend}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Putting the legend outside the axis box leads to this unpleasant behavior.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[5]
%%% The next figure is adjusted to fit %%%
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background]
  \begin{axis}[
    width = 0.76\linewidth, % This value only works for this plot
    xlabel=x axis label,
    ylabel=y axis label,
    legend pos = {outer north east},
  ]
  \addplot[red] {exp(x)};\addlegendentry{legend}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{In this case the width has been adjusted manually so that plot and legend fit into the column.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `tikzscale` is written for this purpose to automatically calculate the parameters to get the requested image size.
The `tikzpicture` is stored in a separate file, e.g. `\jobname-fig1.tikz` and included via `\includegraphics` with key `width`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-fig1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background]
  \begin{axis}[
    width = 0.76\linewidth, % This value only works for this plot
    xlabel=x axis label,
    ylabel=y axis label,
    legend pos = {outer north east},
  ]
  \addplot[red] {exp(x)};\addlegendentry{legend}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\jobname-fig1}
  \caption{In this case the width has been adjusted manually so that plot and
    legend fit into the column.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Update for the environment `filecontents*`

LaTeX has updated the `filecontents` environments allowing an optional argument `force` for overwriting existing files (LaTeX News, Issue 30, October 2019).

Instead of

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
...
\begin{filecontents*}{<filename>}
```

the following can now be used (without package `filecontents`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{<filename>}
```

Comment: Your screenshots always look really nice!

Comment: This answer works great. Small note: You no longer need to include the filecontents package anymore, since it is obsolete. You can use the filecontents environment defined by the LaTeX kernel instead.

Comment: @mab0189 Thanks, I have updated the answer.